# Error while using clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I use the following code to hide and show a div every 1 sec

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var acc = setInterval(function(){
        $("#element").fadeOut(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#element").fadeIn()  
            }, 1000)    
        })
    }, 200)
})

$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(acc);
    }, 10000)
})
```

The `clearInterval()` is not working as it should and I get the following error on Google Chrome:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: acc is not defined**

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/4GWvM/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a scope issue in your code, you have defined the `acc` variable locally in the context of the document ready handler and it's not defined in the context of `load` handler.

Comment: Great username/answer combo here :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try redefining your `acc` variable *outside* the `.ready` callback.

```
var _acc = function(callback) {
    return setInterval(callback, 1000);
};

var acc = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    acc = _acc(function() {
        $("#element").fadeOut(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#element").fadeIn()  
            }, 1000)    
        })
    });
});

...
```